# How to control the number of Spark tasks when writing to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

Using spark on mesos with kafka and cassandra (thus the spark-cassandra-connector)
With spark-streaming I am listening to a kafka topic then inserting in cassandra with .saveToCassandra

I have 60 cpus allocated to spark (30 spark nodes and 5 cassandra nodes)and I am trying to follow apache spark recommendation "In general, we recommend 2-3 tasks per CPU core in your cluster". That is to say 120-180 tasks.

However it seems that the inserting stage has a number of tasks depending on the input data received.

Example (my streaming batch lasts 1 minute):

```
 900 per minute -> inserting stage has 12 tasks
 50 000 per minute -> inserting stage has 380 tasks
```

How can I get:

```
x per minute -> inserting stage has 180 tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call repartition before to save the data in cassandra, so you can change the parallelism to your "Magic Number of tasks", also you can set the default parallelism as a conf parameter of spark